# Kernel.system call from rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundler, gemfile

I am invoking a shell script using `Kernel.system` from my Rails controller. The shell script might invoke another Ruby script based on some conditions. This Ruby script requires the twitter gem. My Rails app is running in apache using Passenger. Now when this Ruby script is invoked from my Rails app, I get the following error in apache logs.

```
/var/www/webapps/test/twitter/twitter_post.rb:2:in `require': no such file to load -- twitter (LoadError)
        from /var/www/webapps/test/twitter/twitter_post.rb:2
```

The same Ruby script runs fine from the Linux shell. Now, if I list the twitter gem in my Gemfile, it works perfectly. `Kernel.system` is supposed to invoke the commands in a subshell, so is Rails modifying any environment variables in its execution shell?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A subshell has the same environment as the process that spawned it, so the right thing is occurring here, since Bundler overwrites Ruby's load path with its own to ensure only the gems in the Gemfile get loaded.

If your app depends on this process running, and that process depends on the twitter gem, why is it not in your Gemfile anyway? Further, why are you executing Ruby in a subshell from Ruby in the first place? There's usually no reason you shouldn't just have that Ruby code within your app.

Comment: Commented below on why I have to call ruby from a shell. And it looks like the new shell gets the following environment variables. `BUNDLE_GEMFILE=/opt/test/Gemfile
RAILS_ENV=production
RUBYOPT=-I/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.14/lib -rbundler/setup
BUNDLE_BIN_PATH=/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.0.14/bin/bundle`

Comment: @Vasu It doesn't really matter *why* you're doing it, but that, as I state in my answer, Bundler (which is loaded when Rails boots) overwrites the load path and thus only the gems in your Gemfile can be loaded.

Comment: Understood what you mean. I was curious about the environment variables which causes this. Will do some research on these. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

you should not be making a system call to another ruby script, you should require or include the contents of the other ruby script.

That being said, your current rubygems environment when you invoke the rails server will be that of the rails application's bundle.  If the rails application's bundle does not include the gems that your other ruby script requires, then your other ruby script will not be able to require that library.

So, add to your rails app's Gemfile the the library that the other script is complaining it is missing and I think that should do ya.

In your external ruby script try:

```
require 'bundler/setup'
```

taken from [bundler setup docs](http://gembundler.com/bundler_setup.html)

Comment: I do a system("/var/www/webapps/test/poll.sh") in my action controller. The "poll.sh" has its own logic and does a "ruby /var/www/webapps/test/twitter/twitter_post.rb". This ruby file has :  require 'twitter'. Yes, it works if I list the twitter gem in my rails Gemfile, but since twitter_post.rb is invoked from a bash shell, I would think it should work, unless rails is changing some environment variable.

Comment: I think what's happening is that the bundler environment is not loaded for the external ruby script when you run it.  I'll do some searching and see if I can find a solution for that.

Comment: try requiring 'bundler/setup' in your external ruby script.  (lifted from http://gembundler.com/bundler_setup.html)

Comment: Please note the env variables I have posted in the comment on the post above. RUBYOPT is set to use bundler, so I dont think I have to do a `require 'bundler/setup'` explicitly.